# Kernel of finitely additive function on $\mathbf{N}$ and Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, borel-sets

Let $f: \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N}) \to [0,1]$ be a finitely additive function such that

- $f(\mathbf{N})=1$;
- $f(X+h)=f(X)$ for all $X\subseteq \mathbf{N}$ and $h \in \mathbf{N}$;
- $f(kX)=\frac{1}{k}f(X)$ for all $X\subseteq \mathbf{N}$ and $k \in \mathbf{N}$, where $kX=\{kx: x \in X\}$.

(It can be shown in ZFC that a function $f$ of this type exists.) It is easy to see that
$$
Z_f:=\{X\subseteq \mathbf{N}: f(X)=0\}
$$
is not a maximal ideal (or equivalently $Z_f^c$ is not an ultrafilter): indeed $f(2\mathbf{N})=f(2\mathbf{N}+1)=1/2$ so there exists a partition of $\mathbf{N}$ in two sets not belonging to $Z_f$. Recall that ultrafilters are not analytic subsets of $\{0,1\}^\mathbf{N}$. Hence it would make sense to ask the following related question:

> **Question**. Is it true that $Z_f$ is not a Borel subset of $\{0,1\}^\mathbf{N}$?

Comment: Well, it's consistent without choice that no such $f$ exists. So I imagine that no such $Z_f$ can be proved to exist without choice, so in all likelihood it's not a Borel set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ???

Comment: @NotMike:!!!!!!

Comment: @AsafKaragila $f(A) = \limsup_n ( \lim_m (\vert A \cap [n,m]\vert / m))$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila whoops it's only sub-additive. Nevermind.

Comment: @NotMike Yep, the upper Banach density is not additive indeed. If I am not wrong, it is not possible to write "explicitly" an expression for such functions

Comment: @NotMike: Well, too bad. You could have proved that ZF is inconsistent...

Comment: @AsafKaragila honesty misread the question, I'd just finished writing an answer about analytic P-ideals and got "excited". So sue me.

Comment: @NotMike: Okay. I will send an email to my lawyer to start drafting the lawsuit papers.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti yes you are correct, when I first saw the question, I misread and jumped to finitely sub-additive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Cool. Make sure everything is written with a snide and conscending tone.

Comment: $Z_f$ cannot have the property of Baire. Suppose it does and say $Z_f$ is meager. Then it is easy to construct a perfect set $P \subseteq 2^{\omega} \setminus Z_f$ of pairwise almost disjoint subsets of $\omega$. If $Z_f$ is comeager in some clopen set, then we can find $x, y \in Z_f$ such that $x \cup y = \omega$. Both cases are impossible.